# Error: not an enclosing class error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm new in developing android apps and i don't have much knowledge in java so i'm stuck here :/
i'm trying to make a new FetchWeatherTask and call execute method on it
can u tell me what should i do to make my code works fine ?

here is MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.android.sunshine33;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean hasOptionsMenu;

    @Override
    //onCreate is called to do initial creation of the fragment.
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); //to indicate that we want call backs for the below methods
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //how to handle clicks on my buttons,....
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh)
        {
            ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu) {
        this.hasOptionsMenu = hasMenu;
    }
}
```

here is ForecastFragment.java

> package com.example.android.sunshine33;

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }
    //onCreateView is where the UI gets initialized
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ArrayList<String> forecastList = new ArrayList<String>()
        {{
            add("Today-Sunny-88/63");
            add("Tomorrow-Foggy-70/46");
            add("Weds-Cloudy-72/63");
            add("Thurs-Rainy-64/51");
            add("Fri-Foggy-70/46");
            add("Sat-Sunny-76/68");
        }};
        ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), // The current context
                R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID. already mwgood fel prog
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                forecastList);
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); //msh fhmah??????????????
        //binding between listView & adapter
        ListView L = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast); //search for listView's ID
        L.setAdapter(forecastAdapter); //b3ml set ll adapter 3la l mkan 2lli feh l listview


        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String mode="json";
        String units="metric";
        int DaysNumber=7;
        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";

            String apiKey = "&APPID=" +"bb30d8f31d6987dc5debd8ac4eddc989";
            final String API_Key_Param="bb30d8f31d6987dc5debd8ac4eddc989";
            final String City_ID_Param="q";
            final String mode_Param=mode;
            final String units_Param=units;
            final int DaysNumber_Param=DaysNumber;
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl.concat(apiKey));

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return rootview;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but I'm pretty sure you need to use `public static class FetchWeatherTask ...`.

Comment: @TylerSebastian how can i use ur solution to solve my problem? could u plz explain more?

Comment: look at my solution below. You need to change the nest FetchWeatherTask class from an inner class (`public class FetchWeatherTask...`) to a static nested class (`public static class FetchWeatherTask...`) - literally, just add `static`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

Use:

```
 public static class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

You are not instantiating **ForecastFragment** in your **MainActivity**; therefore **FetchWeatherTask** (which is a nested class of **ForecastFragment**) needs to be declared **static**

Comment: please select best answer

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so my comment should be correct. You'll need to change

```
public class ForecastFragment {
    ...
    public class FetchWeatherTask {
    ...
    }
}
```

to

```
public class ForecastFragment {
    ...
    public static class FetchWeatherTask {
    ...
    }
}
```

This is because `FetchWeatherClass`, as an inner class (read: how you original had it, without static), "[is associated with an instance of its enclosing class...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)" Whereas *static* nested classes are not.